# Getting around a UNC path error

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd, unc

I'm trying to run a batch file off of a Server in an R script.

```
shell(shQuote(paste("\\\\SERVER\\Folder1\\Folder2\\File.bat", var1, var2), "cmd"))
```

However, "I get a UNC paths are not supported" error. I believe there is something about how I need to handle the quotes. If I want to run the batch file off of the cmd window, I have to put quotes around the file path.

Comment: Is there `cd /d %~dp0` in your .bat file?

Comment: @wOxxOm No there isn't.

Comment: CMD would display a similar error if that was the case... Anyway try the preferred `system2()` function which accepts arguments array separately without the need to deal with quotes inside quotes and without `shQuote` and `paste`.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem:

```
shell(paste(shQuote("\\\\Server\\d$\\SERVER\\Folder1\\Folder2\\file.bat"), var1, var2), "cmd")
```